# Can docker images not have an attached OS?

Tags: docker, operating-system

I was attempting to figure out what OS https://yauaa.basjes.nl/ ran on
also looked for the docker file in the repo  https://github.com/nielsbasjes/yauaa

Ran the suggested docker run/create commands but they only revealed tomcat/java version usage.

exported it to a tar and viewed the tar contents which have references to debian stuff.  But I'd like to know the exact version of debian the image is running

Comment: From the [website](https://yauaa.basjes.nl/): "This is a java library that tries to parse and analyze ....", so in the docker there's only JAVA ? (and some code might be needed to run it on any version of Debian, but then there should also be some code (if needed) to run it on Windows). Or, shorter, the image  does not depend on a specific OS. (I do not know the image builde, maybe I should have said: "should not depend")

Comment: I was stuck on the idea that all docker images needed some kind of OS in them.  Thank you for the explanation.